# How to speed up for loop on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, subtraction

I need to convert a for loop to a set of functions that will cycle through the data faster. It is cycling through a dataframe and subtracting values. I thought of mapping the dataframe but it isn't the clearest concept to me and I could use whatever help is offered.

```
for nd in wnkd['days'].unique():
    for ld in lps['level'].unique():
        nmrtr = []
        for ty in types:
            try:
                nmrtr.append((sum(wnkd.loc[(wnkd['level']== ld) & (wnkd['typs'] == ty) & (wnkd['data_set'] == 'rules'),'FRQ'].values)-(
                            sum(wnkd.loc[(wnkd['level']== ld) & (wnkd['typs']== ty ) & (wnkd['data_set'] == 'actual'), 'FRQ']))))
            except (KeyError,IndexError) as e:
                nmrtr.append(0)
        print(nmrtr,ld)
        nmrtr.append(ld)
        nmrtr.append(nd)
```

The try/ except is in place because if a values doesn't exist within this section of the for loop it may fall within another section. For example when ld is 3 and type is car there may not be any values but there may be a value when ld is 4 and type is car. The goal is to cycle through each section of the data by week date(nd) then level (ld) then type (ty) to compare the values from 2 different data sets. FRQ refers to the frequency that was generated by grouping the original data sets. Also note that just because actual has nd = 3/1 , level = 4 and type = car doesn't mean that rules will have the same type. Rules will have the same nd and level but the type may vary. I'm solving to find how often the types vary.

Comment: When you use `map` there's always a 1-to-1 correspondence between input and output elements. But your loop appends multiple elements in each iteration, so you can't use `map()`.

Comment: The inside is subtracting 2 values is this not 1 to 1? I'm not sure what I'd need to alter to make it fit. I just really need to speed up this loop.

Comment: I'm talking about all the calls to `nmrtr.append()`. You call it multiple times each iteration.

Comment: `map()` won't speed it up significantly.

Comment: Are these dictionaries or pandas series?

Comment: Got you, thank you so much for this information and its a pandas df do you think making it a dictionary and then running will help? This currently takes hours because there are more than 100k rows

Comment: Just trying to understand what you're trying to do. Usually with pandas you don't write all these explicit loops.

Comment: Its a df but I'm cycling through to make calculations on 2 separate rows. I wasn't aware of a better way to compare the rows. Its a dataframe that is made of 2 datasets and subtracts the similar rows. I couldn't only think of separating them out by looping through them.

Comment: I can't help too much with the pandas-specific aspects, sorry.